What is a simpler method to find the analytical expression for the function f[x]?
Given the following conditions, find the analytical expression for the function f[x]
f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x

My method is as follows:
Reduce[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x] == t && t >= 2 && x > 0, x]

(t == 2 && 
   x == 1) || (t > 
    2 && (x == 1/2 (-2 + t^2) - 1/2 Sqrt[-4 t^2 + t^4] || 
     x == 1/2 (-2 + t^2) + 1/2 Sqrt[-4 t^2 + t^4]))

1/(1/2  (-2 + t^2) - 1/2  Sqrt[-4 t^2 + t^4]) + 1/2  (-2 + t^2) - 
  1/2  Sqrt[-4 t^2 + t^4] // Simplify

-2 + t^2


And this method also cannot directly yield the analytical expression for f[x]
RSolve[{f[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] == x + 1/x, f[2] == 2}, f[x], x]


(-1) You're using RSolve blindly.

Eliminate[{f == x + 1/x, t == Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]}, x]
(*    t^2 == 2 + f    *)

from which $f(t)=t^2-2$ follows immediately with Solve[%, f].
Or, with some branch warnings (and thus less safe),
Solve[{f == x + 1/x, t == Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]}, {f, x}]
(*    {{f -> -2 + t^2, x -> 1/2 (-2 + t^2 - t Sqrt[-4 + t^2])},
       {f -> -2 + t^2, x -> 1/2 (-2 + t^2 + t Sqrt[-4 + t^2])}}    *)


Simplify your equation by replacing x by x^2:
f[x + 1/x] == x^2 + 1/x^2

Then we replace the argument of f by y== x + 1/x and solve for x:
sol=Solve[y == x + 1/x, x]

{{x -> 1/2 (y - Sqrt[-4 + y^2])}, {x -> 1/2 (y + Sqrt[-4 + y^2])}}

With this we get an analytic functions:
{f1[y_], f2[y_]} = x^2 + 1/x^2 /. sol // Simplify

{-2 + y^2, -2 + y^2}

As both functions are identical:
fres[y_]= -2+y^2

To check if this is correct:
fres[Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x]] // Simplify

1/x + x


I would like to stress here the fact that a functional equation like this one :
$$f(x+1/x)=x^2+1/x^2 \ (\text{with} \ x > 0) \tag{1}$$
can be solved without needing any software in the following manner.
Setting $x=e^{u}$, (1) can be written :
$$f(2 \cosh u)=\cosh 2u \tag{2}$$
Otherwise said, setting $v=2 \cosh u \iff u=\operatorname{arcosh}(v/2)$ :
$$f(v)=\cosh(2 \operatorname{arcosh}(v/2)$$
where we recognize a conjugation relation : $f=h \circ g \circ  h^{-1}$

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Dear robot, I think my answer is completely in correspondence with the title of the question : I have given a "simpler method" for solving this issue. It is true that I do not use Mathematica, but I am very explicit on that :; anyhow, I don't think my answer is "unclear".

For some reason the OP frequently asks the site how to solve simple math problems with Mathematica, which sometimes attracts a variety of criticism (lack of clarity, simplicity of the problem, RTFM being common). But I agree with your comment.

From general solution to specific:
Quiet[
 sol = Solve[Eliminate[{f[g[x]] == h[x], t == g[x]}, x], f[t]];
 Block[{g = x |-> Sqrt[x] + 1/Sqrt[x], h = x |-> x + 1/x}, 
  sol // Simplify],
 {InverseFunction::ifun, Solve::ifun}]
(*  {{f[t] -> -2 + t^2}}  *)

